# Using storybook inside git submodule

Tags: reactjs, git, git-submodules, storybook

I have a submodule with shared components for several electron-react apps. Adding a Storybook to every app project will be inconvenient, so I want to try to initialize it inside the submodule. Is it possible and ok to do this? Are there any pitfalls?